# Can't boot into system after changing setup

Tags: boot, system-installation

I recently upgraded my server from an and platform to intel. I disconnected the drive and connected to another motherboard. Now it doesn’t boot into the system. Anyone know how to fix it or do I need to reinstall it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgECF.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information. For example: from what (AMD?) mobo to what Intel mobo? What is the kernel version? What else info do you consider to be relevant? And - as mentioned - the output of `journalctl -xb` would also be interesting.